# first object of array not being passed into initialValue parameter in reduce()

Tags: javascript, arrays

This is my code:

```
var deliveries = [
  {
    "id": 1,
    "destination": 'Oakland',    
    "orderPrice": 75,
    "rushDelivery": true,
    "rushDeliveryFee": 12.75,
    "orderDate": "4 April 2016" 
  },
  {
    "id": 2,
    "destination": 'San Jose',    
    "orderPrice": 62.75,
    "orderDate": "5 April 2016" 
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "destination": 'San Francisco',    
    "orderPrice": 15.00,
    "rushDelivery": true,
    "rushDeliveryFee": 50.75,
    "orderDate": "10 April 2016" 
  },
  {
    "id": 4,
    "destination": 'San Francisco',    
    "orderPrice": 25,
    "orderDate": "4/11/2016"
  },
  {
    "id": 5,
    "destination": 'San Francisco',    
    "orderPrice": 90,
    "rushDelivery": true,
    "rushDeliveryFee": 30,
    "orderDate": "April 12, 2015"
  },
  {
    "id": 6,
    "destination": 'Berkeley',    
    "orderPrice": 45,
    "orderDate": "4/01/2015"
  },
  {
    "id": 7,
    "destination": 'Berkeley',    
    "orderPrice": 62.16,
    "orderDate": "12 April 2016"
  }
];


var orderPrices = deliveries.reduce(function(prev, current) {
    return prev.orderPrice + current.orderPrice
})

console.log(orderPrices);
```

When I `console.log` `prev.orderPrice` in the first iteration of `reduce()` it prints `undefined`, but from what I understand, if you give no second argument(the `initialValue`) to `reduce()`, it simply defaults to the first element of the array to which you apply the function to. I would expect the first object of the array to be printed. In fact, if we try this with another simpler array  like `var arr = [1,2,3,4,5]`, `prev` prints 1 in the first iteration.

Why is this happening?

Comment: I tried your code with an added `console.log(prev)` in the callback and it correctly logged the first item. But that code wouldn't work regardless of what happens on the *first* iteration, because on the *second* iteration `prev` would be the number returned from the first iteration, not an object, so the final result is `NaN`.

Comment: Use `return prev + current.orderPrice;` and `0` as the second argument to the `reduce` function.

Comment: And I don't think it can be reproduced either, there's just no way it would be `undefined` ?

Comment: @Xufox, the thing is I am trying to avoid using that second argument for the sake of understanding why this isn't working. nnnnnn has a really good point. I think that is part of the reason why my logic isn't working here

Comment: @nnnnnn yes you are 100% correct. I missed that logic. I am going to try to fix this. My goal is to return the total sum of all orderPrices in the array without giving reduce a second argument of 0

Comment: @nnnnnn try to `console.log(prev.orderPrice)`. It tells me `Cannot read property 'orderPrice' of undefined `. That is why I said `prev` was undefined before. Yet if we just `console.log(prev)` it prints the first object. Why can't I access the property orderPrice if the object exists?

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/j6Lc500k/1/ <- like that ?

Comment: If you have `console.log(prev.orderPrice)` then it will be the *second* iteration that logs `undefined`, not the first, because on the second iteration `prev` will be a number, and `someNumber.orderPrice` is `undefined`. Regarding your goal, `return (prev.orderPrice || prev) + current.orderPrice` will do it, but that forces an additional `||` operation on every iteration so just passing in a second argument of `0` is better.

Comment: @nnnnnn  ahhhh of course! because I'm not returning anything. Makes complete sense now

Comment: @adeneo thank you for the jsfiddle, I'm just figuring out right now why you needed the ternary operators and checking in there

Comment: @adeneo makes sense. If you put it as an answer ill approve it. Perhaps a little bit explanation of why you did what you did for anybody that encounters my same confusion

Comment: @nnnnnn just reread your edited comment. I agree 100% passing the second argument is better. I just wanted to understand why it wasn't working. Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The elements in array are reduced 1 by 1 from left to right. Thus, from the second iteration, the `prev` argument is the current total value already:

```
    var orderPrices = deliveries.reduce(function (prev, current) {
        if (prev.orderPrice)
        {
            return prev.orderPrice + current.orderPrice;
        }
        return prev + current.orderPrice;
    });

    console.log(orderPrices);
```

Comment: @torazaburo, he does explain why it's happening "Thus, from the second iteration, the prev argument is the current total value already". That is exactly why I was getting `undefined` whenever I printed `prev.orderPrice`.  Prev was a number on the second iteration and did not have an `orderPrice` property. I realize this is not the best solution, but the solution explains why my solution didn't work